# Neither Default Constructor nor Copy Constructor is called when using anonymous object

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor, move-constructor, most-vexing-parse

Below is the snippet aimed to test the constructors. It was run in VS 2015.

In my opinion, "B b(B())" has the same function as "B b = B()", however, my code seems to say that they behave different.

I know there's copy elision by compiler optimization, but I think the default constructor should be called at least when execute "B b(B())".
Can anyone help point out where my misunderstood is?

```
class B
{
public:
    B() {
        ++i;
        x = new int[100];
        cout << "default constructor!"<<" "<<i << endl;
        cout << "x address:" << x << endl << "--------" << endl;
    }
    B(const B &b)  //copy constructor
    {   
        ++i;
        cout << "Copy constructor & called " << i<< endl 
            << "--------" << endl;
    }
    B(B &&b)//move constructor
    {
        x = b.x;    
        ++i;
        b.x = nullptr;
        cout << "Copy constructor && called" << i << endl 
            <<"x address:"<< x << endl << "--------" << endl;

    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "b address:" << x << endl << "--------" << endl;
    }
private:
    static int i;
    int *x;
};
int B::i = 0;


int main()
{
    B b1; //default constructor
    b1.print();
    B b2 = B(); //default constructor only
    b2.print();
    B b3(B());  //????nothing called... why???
    B b4 = b2; //copy constructor
    B b5 = move(b2); //move constructor
    b2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `B b(B())` is a function declaration, not a variable definition at all, then no constructor would be called.

According to [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), `B b(B())` is a function declaration, for a function named `b` which returns an object of type `B` and has a single (unnamed) parameter which is a pointer to function returning type `B` and taking no parameter.

You can solve it by using braces ([list initlization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11)), like

```
B b1( B{} );
B b2{ B() };
B b3{ B{} };  // preferable from C++11
```

Comment: Nice catch! @Shirley Feng, according to the wiki article, you can get the expected behavior by adding parenthesis around your inner ctor call. Example: `B b3( (B()) );`

Comment: Thank you for the share!! It saves me XD

Comment: Just wonder, shouldn't it be better to keep using one convention for initialization? i.e. `B b{ B{} };` instead

Comment: @AdrianShum You're right. I just want to point out that only using one pair of braces would solve the ambiguity here.

Comment: @ShirleyFeng Yes! It's a really important C++11 feature.

Comment: @songyuanyao  Hi, I have a new doubt about the call of copy constructor regarding anonymous object.  B b1{ move(B{}) }; can call the move constructor. but is there anyway that we can trigger the copy constructor when initialize an object with another anonymous one? Thanks!

Comment: @ShirleyFeng What do you want to achieve? You can write a function similar with `std::move`, like `B foo(const B& b) { return b; }`, then `B b{ foo(B{}) };`.